# How to toggle section cells in UITableViewController in SWIFT?

Tags: swift, uitableview, mobile-application

I'm new to iOS mobile application development and Swift. I'm trying to implement a UITableViewController which can do the following:

- Upon clicking any of the section headers the cells corresponding to that particular section should drop down.
- Upon clicking the section headers which have 0 cells a segue should be triggered and pushed to another ViewController.

*0 cells -> push to a different ViewController.

n cells -> dropdown*

How do I achieve this in Swift?

I tried the following code in UITableViewController to toggle, but, in vain.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let frame: CGRect = tableView.frame

    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, frame.size.width-10, 80)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "menuButtonAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    if section == 1 {
        button.setTitle("Home", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }else if section == 2 {
        button.setTitle("Profile", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }else if section == 3 {
        button.setTitle("Projects", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }else {
        button.setTitle("Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, 150))
    headerView.addSubview(button)

    return headerView;
}

var enabledCategory:Bool = false

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if (section == 3 && enabledCategory){
        return dataHandler.getNumberOfProjects()
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("menuCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    if indexPath.section == 3 {
        cell!.customLabel.text = String(indexPath.row)
    }
    return cell!
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 3 {
        enabledCategory = !enabledCategory
        tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 3) , withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

And, I've no idea of how to push to a different ViewController by clicking on sections 1 and 2.

Thanks.

Comment: No. You should provide what you have tried then we can help improve upon that.  No one will write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Default UITableView headers views are not clickable. You should implement  `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` method of `UITableViewDelegate` and provide your own `UIView` with `UIButton` or some clickable element

Comment: I've added a UIButton in viewForHeaderInSection method. How do I proceed further to toggle cells and push to a different ViewController?